# Android: Is onResume always called after onCreate?

Tags: android

I need to know if there is ever an instance when `onResume` will be called before `onCreate` has been called at least once. Thanks.

Edit: Judging by the activity life cycle, it doesn't seem so. But I want to double check.

Comment: In Google Play "Android Vitals / ANR & Crashes" section I have noticed, that `onResume` is called by [callActivityOnResume](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#callActivityOnResume(android.app.Activity)) without `onCreate` being called before - which resulted in NPE for my app.

Comment: Having same issues here. I have an `ID` filed in my singleton object which is initialized in `onCreate`. But there is an `NullPointerException` in Crashlytics which shows my `ID` is null while it's calling `onResume`.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

`onResume()` will never be called before `onCreate()`.

Read more about it in the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

[image: Activity Lifecycle]

Answer (score 16):

`onResume()` *will always be called* when the activity goes into foreground, but it will *never* be executed before `onCreate()`.

Comment: `onResume()` will also be called the first time, when the activity has been created, right?

Comment: I think yes. am trying a way to stop it now

Answer (score 9):

[image: This is basic activity life cycle which would help you understand better]

you can refer the website for more details
                                                 http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Answer (score 9):

I had an issue in which overridden onCreate was **not** getting called. I tried debugging and logging and i found oncreate not getting called.

Turns out that i override wrong onCreate

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    }
```

This is the correct one.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Posting in the hope that it might help some poor soul. :)

So the correct onCreate() will always get called before onResume

Comment: Poor soul helped!  Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** This answer only an additional one to complement [the accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12116144/4758255).

As previous answers say:

`onResume() will never be called before onCreate().`

Read more about it in the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and [Starting an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html).

Below the complete image of **Activity lifecycle** including **Fragment Lifecycle** from [android-lifecycle](https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the activity has its own lifecycle . just read and look at the nice graph here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

onResume doesn't suppose to run before onCreate , so you assume correctly .