# How do I refresh the contents of a webview everytime the app is launched?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-websettings, android-webservice

I am trying to refresh the contents of my webview everytime someone launches my app.Say someone goes to a different page within the app or goes to background and then relaunches the app, i want the contents of my webview to refresh/reload based on the latest changes I have done on my server.
Here's the code I have so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webview;
    ProgressBar progress; 
    public final static int MENU_FULLSCREEN_ON = 3;
    public final static int MENU_FULLSCREEN_OFF = 4;
    private boolean fullscreen = true;
    public static Object SPLASH_LOCK = new Object();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       // getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);


         if(CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(MainActivity.this))
        {
        webview.setInitialScale(1);
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
      //  webview.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
            webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webview.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
       webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
       // webview.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads(true);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
        webview.clearCache(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://myserver.com/firstpage");
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        //http://www.inpixelitrust.fr/demos/restaurant_picker/
        //file:///android_asset/index.html
        webview.reload();
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
         }else{
              Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
              toast.show(); 
              AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
              alertDialog.setTitle("Connection Problem");
              alertDialog.setMessage("You need to be connected to the internet to view this app");
              alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                  public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                      return;
                  }
              });
              alertDialog.show();

        }
       /* webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {
         public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
         {
           // update the progressBar
           MainActivity.this.setProgress(progress * 100);
         }
        });*/
        if (!isTaskRoot()) {
            final Intent intent = getIntent();
            final String intentAction = intent.getAction();
            if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && intentAction != null && intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }

        setFullscreen();
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(webview.canGoBack() == true){
                    webview.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

      menu.add(0, MENU_FULLSCREEN_ON, 0, R.string.menu_fullscreen_on);
      menu.add(0, MENU_FULLSCREEN_OFF, 0, R.string.menu_fullscreen_off);


      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
      super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

      menu.findItem(MENU_FULLSCREEN_ON).setVisible(!fullscreen);
      menu.findItem(MENU_FULLSCREEN_OFF).setVisible(fullscreen);

      return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {

      case MENU_FULLSCREEN_ON:
        fullscreen = true;
        setFullscreen();
        return true;
      case MENU_FULLSCREEN_OFF:
        fullscreen = false;
        setFullscreen();
        return true;

      }
      return false;
    }
    private void setFullscreen()
    {
      if (fullscreen) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
      } else {
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
      }

    }
/*
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

          setFullscreen();


    }*/


    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            //view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
          public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            synchronized (SPLASH_LOCK) {
                SPLASH_LOCK.notifyAll();
            }
          }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onResume()` is called when the activity returns to the foreground. You can place your reload in there. Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    webView.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the onResume(){} then just load the url again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, but make sure you check that the `WebView` is not null since `onResume` is called prior to `onCreate` and `WebView` may not exist in `onResume` yet!

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(webView != null){
        webView.loadUrl(...);
        or
        webView.reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would go with this answer if the webview is supposed to show a static page, where the user isn't supposed to go into another "screen" through the webview. Otherwise the answer by @ChrisS should work fine (but be sure to check if the webview is null)

Comment: The user navigates through a webview say index.html is the first page and it has references to other pages like secondpage.html and back. It would be cooler ,if it could refresh everytime user goes back and forth.Is the above code perfect for that?

Comment: reload will "reload" his current page.. while if you call loadUrl(".../index.htm") it will reload index page... it depends what you want to reload

Comment: I was able to refresh properly as expected. However, I lost my keystore and wanted to see if I can update the view from within the html webview files?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by keystore? Otherwise you can write a JavaScript function to do the reload and call it like this myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:myJavaScriptReloadFunction()");

Comment: I lost my app signing key, so planning to refresh within html now

Comment: That is wrong; onResume is never called before onCreate - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12116144/446791